# python findall to match the string that are all capitalized

Tags: python

I am trying to use python re.findall to match string with following conditions:

```
contain all uppercase letters
have numbers present sometimes
```

I tried

```
ab_list = re.findall(r'([A-Z]+)(\.\d+)', text)
```

but this does not return anything.

Comment: Your current pattern seems to be trying to match strings like `ABC.123`, `XYZ.4`, etc, (which it does). Are you sure you've got your conditions right? Perhaps you should show some example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = ["ALL CAPITALS ARE ON", "Some lower, soMe not", "AGAIN, WITH PUNCTIONATION."]
final_data = [i for i in s if re.findall("^[A-Z0-9\W]+$", i)]
```

Output:

```
['ALL CAPITALS ARE ON', 'AGAIN, WITH PUNCTIONATION.']
```

If you are trying to find words that are all capitalized:

```
s = ["NOT (LOWER)", "Some lower, soMe not", "AGAIN, WITH PUNCTIONATION.", "young 10 (MODY10)"]
final_data = [b for b in [re.findall("(?<=\().*?(?=\))", i) for i in s] if b and re.findall("^[A-Z0-9\W]+$", b[0])]
final_data = [b for b in [re.findall("\(([A-Z0-9\W])\)", i) for i in s] if b]
```

Output:

```
[['LOWER'], ['MODY10']]
```

If you have one long string:

```
s = 'NOT (LOWER)Some lower, soMe notAGAIN, WITH PUNCTIONATION.young 10 (MODY10)'
final_strings = re.findall("\(([A-Z0-9\W]+)\)", s)
```

Output:

```
['LOWER', 'MODY10']
```

Comment: Thanks but it's actually number present sometimes, not punctuations

Comment: I am trying to get "MODY10" from "young 10 (MODY10)" that one doesnt work.

Comment: @user6792790 that is because this regex only finds capital sentences from start to end, while "young 10 (MODY10)" is not comprised of purely capital letters with other non alphanumeric characters. I will change my answer to support what you are trying to do now.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I want to find a 1) All capital case 2) numbers optional character that's inside a parenthesis.

Comment: @user6792790 Do the words all have to be inside parenthesis?

Comment: Yes. So "aaa (AAA)" would have to parse AAA

Comment: Thanks thats great. But how can we make it if we want to process a long string, not a list of strings?

Comment: @user6792790 Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

This will find strings containing only uppercase letters, numbers, and spaces.

```
re.findall('^[A-Z0-9 ]+$', text)
```

This will return a list containing the string if it matches, otherwise, it returns an empty list. If you just want to detect whether the whole string matches, though, it might be more straightforward to use `re.match` rather than `re.findall`. That depends on what you're ultimately trying to do.

If you want to instead find the individual words, you might want:

```
re.findall('([A-Z0-9]+)', text)
```